# Characters are being replaced to ? symbol when using copy command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to load csv file to redshift table using copy command.

Special symbols like pound £ in varchar columns are converted to question mark "?" (which is default with redshift). How to copy over the special symbols as well?

below is my aws copy command

`COPY public.sales FROM 's3://mybucket/salesfile.csv' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::99999999999:role/RedShiftRole' delimiter ',' ignoreheader 1 acceptinvchars`

Comment: The default encoding for the copy command is UTF8, which should be fine for a £. you will need to double check the encoding and data in your source file.

Comment: Hi Jon, you're right, the source csv file is in ANSI encoding. changing it to utf-8 clears out the error. thank you. is there any way we can achieve this in aws lambda or python script?

Answer (score 1):

Has your data been extracted from SQL Server? If so it's likely in UTF-16LE and you need to add that as a parameter in your `COPY`.

```
COPY public.sales 
FROM 's3://mybucket/salesfile.csv' 

ENCODING UTF16LE

IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::99999999999:role/RedShiftRole' 
DELIMITER ',' 
IGNOREHEADER 1 
ACCEPTINVCHARS
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-encoding

Comment: the csv file is extracted from an api, and is in format ANSI. would adding encoding would help my csv convert to UTF-8

Comment: Redshift does support ANSI encoded data. The core ASCII range (0-127) is the same for ANSI and UTF8 which is why some of your data loaded OK. The `£` symbol is not in the core range though. You need to convert the data to UTF8. Recommend `iconv`.